# Spring Cloud Kinesis startup failing after latest Spring Cloud upgrade when running locally

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Before deploying our Spring Cloud microservices (packaged as Docker images) to AWS, we test them locally against LocalStack. As such, we have beans defined like the following in our code base that are autoconfigured:

```
  @Bean("amazonKinesisAsyncMyBean")
  @Primary
  @Conditional(value = {LocalStackProfileCondition.class})
  public AmazonKinesisAsync localAmazonKinesisAsync(
      final LocalStackProfileProperties localStackProfileProperties,
      final LocalStackProperties localStackProperties,
      AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider) {
    System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.AWS_CBOR_DISABLE_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");
    System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.DISABLE_CERT_CHECKING_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");
    return AmazonKinesisAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
        .withEndpointConfiguration(
            new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
                generateUriString(
                    localStackProperties.getProtocol().toLowerCase(),
                    localStackProperties.getHost(),
                    localStackProperties.getKinesis().getPort()),
                localStackProfileProperties.getClient().getRegion()))
        .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
        .build();
  }
```

With Spring Boot 2.3.5.RELEASE, Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR4, and Spring Cloud Stream Binder Kinesis 2.0.1.RELEASE, we are able to successfully test our Docker containers locally against LocalStack. However, after upgrading to Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR9 we are failing with the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to squid.acme.com:8080 [squid.acme.com/x.x.x.x, squid.acme.com/x.x.x.x, squid.acme.com/x.x.x.x] failed: connect timed out
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1207)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1153)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.doInvoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2809)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2776)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2765)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.executeDescribeStream(AmazonKinesisClient.java:875)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.describeStream(AmazonKinesisClient.java:846)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.provisioning.KinesisStreamProvisioner.createOrUpdate(KinesisStreamProvisioner.java:135)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.provisioning.KinesisStreamProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KinesisStreamProvisioner.java:91)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.provisioning.KinesisStreamProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KinesisStreamProvisioner.java:57)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:223)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Our local development environment is walled off from the internet, thus the connection timeout via the proxy. Regardless, the problem in the first place is that after upgrading Spring Cloud it appears the Kinesis binder is trying to connect to AWS to get the shard list. How can I ensure that these requests get routed to LocalStack and not AWS when I am running with the new configuration?

**UPDATE 1:**

After updating Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis Binder to 2.0.3.RELEASE, following is the stack trace I now receive:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to squid.acme.com:8080 [squid.acme.com/x.x.x.x, squid.acme.com/x.x.x.x, squid.acme.com/x.x.x.x] failed: connect timed out
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1207)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1153)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.doInvoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2809)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2776)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2765)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.executeListShards(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1557)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.listShards(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1528)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.provisioning.KinesisStreamProvisioner.getShardList(KinesisStreamProvisioner.java:141)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.provisioning.KinesisStreamProvisioner.getShardList(KinesisStreamProvisioner.java:122)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.provisioning.KinesisStreamProvisioner.createOrUpdate(KinesisStreamProvisioner.java:167)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.provisioning.KinesisStreamProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KinesisStreamProvisioner.java:93)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.provisioning.KinesisStreamProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KinesisStreamProvisioner.java:59)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:223)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

**UPDATE 2:**

After setting `org.springframework` logging level to `DEBUG`, I was able to capture the following Conditions Evaluation Report:

```
============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   ContextCredentialsAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider' (OnClassCondition)

   KinesisBinderConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.Binder; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   KinesisBinderConfiguration#dynamoDBStreams matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBStreams; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   KinesisBinderConfiguration.KinesisBinderHealthIndicatorConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator management.health.defaults.enabled is considered true (OnEnabledHealthIndicatorCondition)

   KinesisBinderConfiguration.KinesisBinderHealthIndicatorConfiguration#kinesisBinderHealthIndicator matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: kinesisBinderHealthIndicator; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------

   KinesisBinderConfiguration#amazonKinesis:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisAsync; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisAsync' amazonKinesisAsyncMyBean (OnBeanCondition)

   KinesisBinderConfiguration#cloudWatch:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchAsync; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchAsync' amazonCloudWatchAsync (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.kpl-kcl-enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   KinesisBinderConfiguration#dynamoDB:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBAsync; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBAsync' amazonDynamoDBAsync (OnBeanCondition)

   KinesisBinderConfiguration#dynamoDBLockRegistry:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.kpl-kcl-enabled=false) found different value in property 'spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.kpl-kcl-enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)

   KinesisBinderConfiguration#kinesisCheckpointStore:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.kpl-kcl-enabled=false) found different value in property 'spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.kpl-kcl-enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)

   KinesisBinderConfiguration#kinesisProducerConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducerConfiguration; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducerConfiguration' kinesisProducerConfiguration (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.kpl-kcl-enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    None
```

Comment: Please, try to upgrade to Kinesis binder `2.0.3` and share with us the stack trace already from there. It looks like I can't correlate your stack trace with the code base.

Comment: Another thought. You mention something like "your own auto-configuration". Did you configure it `before` the `KinesisBinderConfiguration` or `BinderFactoryAutoConfiguration`? I mean we need to ensure somehow that your custom `AmazonKinesisAsync` is really loaded before the Kinesis Binder starts its configuration.

Comment: I updated the binder to 2.0.3 and updated my post with an updated stack trace. @ArtemBilan, how can I tell if my bean is configured before or after the ```KinesisBinderConfiguration``` or ```BinderFactoryAutoConfiguration```? Or better yet, how can I ensure my bean is always configured before these?

Comment: @ArtemBilan, based on the first negative match in my second update that I added to my original post, it appears that my ```AmazonKinesisAsync``` bean is already created by the time the ```KinesisBinderConfiguration``` runs. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look into that condition one more time:

```
 KinesisBinderConfiguration#amazonKinesis:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisAsync; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisAsync' amazonKinesisAsync (OnBeanCondition)
```

Pay attention to the `amazonKinesisAsync` bean name. Doesn't look like it belongs to the mentioned `localAmazonKinesisAsync` bean in your configuration. Probably your conditions doesn't work somehow and another `AmazonKinesisAsync` bean wins which already points to the `squid.acme.com:8080` endpoint...

Comment: I had forgotten to copy the ```@Bean("amazonKinesisAsync")``` line when I originally posted, so the condition actually did match my bean. To be sure, I changed the name to ```@Bean("amazonKinesisAsyncMyBean")``` and reran my testing. I have updated my original post with the full bean definition and most recent conditions evaluation report. You will see that it is, in fact, my bean that is referenced in the condition. My apologies for having omitted the ```@Bean``` line in the first place.

Comment: I don't know then why it try to connect not to the LocalStack. Any chances to share with us a simple project to play with?

Comment: I will have to create a completely separate one. Unfortunately, I am strictly forbidden from sharing any code I am currently working on.

Comment: Sure! But I don't think it needs too much code to create a new plain project. What we need to prove is just a way that LocalStack is used when that `getShardList()` is called. Or LocalStack just doesn't implement that API for us?..